# How to change parent of child fxml into other parent?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

Can I change a `Node`'s parent to another parent in FXML?

Suppose a parent named `stackcon` with a child node.
I now want to move this child node to different parent, e.g., named `stackmain`.

Is this possible? If yes, please give me a link or a example code.

Comment: So, basically, you want to move a certain `Node` from one `Parent` to another `Parent`, i.e., remove it in the first `Parent` and add it to the second `Parent`?

Comment: @MarkusWeninger yes but i don't have any idea how to do that as well as clear that parent where i want to load that child fxmll file

Comment: I added an answer. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one of many ways how to do this.

`MainView.fxml`, just a simple **view** containing a button, and on button click the label should be moved from right to left and vice-versa (see the `onMousePressed` declaration):

```
<fx:root type="BorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <left>
        <VBox fx:id="lefty">
            <Label fx:id="switchy" text="Switching text"></Label>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <Button fx:id="switchBtn" text="Switch" onMousePressed="#switchButtonPressed"></Button>
    </center>
    <right>
        <VBox fx:id="righty">
        </VBox>
    </right>
</fx:root>
```

The **controller** `MainView.java` with its `switchButtonPressed` **event handler**:

```
public class MainView extends BorderPane {
    @FXML private VBox lefty;
    @FXML private VBox righty;
    @FXML private Label switchy;

    public MainView() {
        URL fxmlFile = MainView.class.getResource("MainView.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlFile);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void switchButtonPressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if(lefty.getChildren().contains(switchy)) {
            lefty.getChildren().remove(switchy);
            righty.getChildren().add(switchy);
        } else {
            righty.getChildren().remove(switchy);
            lefty.getChildren().add(switchy);
        }
    }
}
```

You see, I just check on button click if the label is on the left side. If so, remove it on the left side and add it on the right side.
Analogous, if it is on the right side, remove it there and add it on the left side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318424/child-fxml-file-not-loading-to-parent-fxml/45320747#45320747  actually i want solution for this Question

Comment: @Rocky: Yeah, then take the logic I presented, it is totally fine for your problem. Just, instead of a button press, in your problem the event handler has to be registered to the event "when user click on table row". If this answer helped you, please upvote it (and accept it as answer).

Comment: your are switching in single parent fxml view(i.e stackpane are common) but in my case there are superparent pane , parent pane and child  . child get load into parent pane  without an issue but when i m try to load it into super parent pane its throw error stackhome.getChildren().clear(); stackhome.getChildren().add("an.fxml");   stackhome is super parent stack

Comment: @Rocky: Yeah, but you didn't state that in your question, therefore my answer is still correct in regard to your question (and should be marked so). I cannot read your mind that you have a parent / grandparent scenario, you only mentioned that in your other question.

And: "An error is thrown" is nearly never helpful... Post the exact error including error stacks in your questions... I am pretty sure that it has to do with the `clear()` call (see my example, I only use `remove` and `add`, no `clear`).

Answer (score 1):

it may vary depending on type of the pane of `stackmain` & `stackcon` , i'm assuming that you use `AnchorPane`

but it is something like this

```
Node childNode = stackcon.getChildren().get(indexOfChild);
stackcon.getChildren().remove(indexOfChild);
stackmain.getChildren().add(childNode);
```