# Restrict user to give input up to 3 characters in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am new to javaFx so please ignore my silly question here I want to validate (restrict) user to give 3 characters input (if user put more input, it should not allowed or after 3 characters, no latter should be visible) I found many solutions for validation but it does not restricting up to 3 characters as well as it little confusing to understand Here is my code.

```
public class editController {
 @FXML
 private TextField countrycode;
  public void add(ActionEvent event) {
    String ADD=countrycode.getText();
    try {
        if(ADD.isEmpty()){
                Alert alert=new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Please Fill All DATA");
                alert.showAndWait();
                return;
        }


        FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader();
        loader.load(getClass().getResource("/region/newCountry.fxml").openStream());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Validate using textProperty Listener like:

```
countrycode.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (newValue.length() > 3) {
                countrycode.setText(oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
```

Or get a String length and check that like

```
int length = ADD.length();
if (length > 3) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter Lessthen 3 character");
}
```

Comment: it not working   into my code and i do not want to show more than 3 charater if user give input

Comment: I hope this code is helping you! If you solved your problem in this solution, Then don't forgate to accept the answer to helping other in future.

Comment: i want just 3 character is visible if user put more value then it does not allow in the input field

Comment: What's the problem in first solution using textProperty Listener ?

Comment: thanks @keyur bhanderi  can you help me on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318424/child-fxml-file-not-loading-to-parent-fxml/45320747#45320747

Answer (score 1):

you have to @Override the `replaceText(int,int,String)` method of your textField this way:

```
@Override 
public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
    if ("".equals(text)) { // handles delete
        super.replaceText(start, end, text);
        return;
    }
    if (getText().length() < 3) { // handles add and checks length.
        super.replaceText(start, end, text);
    }
}
```

This won't let you to insert more than 3 characters, but you can define any regexp and use instead of the second if condition.

Answer (score 1):

The [solution of @KeyurBhanderi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346888/7214815) is good enough until you are typing char by char. But when you try to paste from the clipboard a long text you will not see any changes in the text field. Surprise!

As alternative to avoid confusing set at least truncated string:

```
field.setText(newValue.substring(0, maxLimit));
```

In this case the end user will see a part of text and will quickly understand what is going on. Even better to show a popup window with a warning.